# ng-container display text from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have a ng-container like this:

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of columns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

I'm trying to display the text in  `<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>` from bottom to top, not from left to right. I tried to use `flex-direction: column`  but it doesn't work. It is possible to do this?

[image]

This is the design of the table I have. I want the text in the columns under Symbol (A,B,C,D,E) to be displayed from from bottom to top not as it is now. Text should be vertical not horizontal.

Comment: Can you please attach an Image which explain what you really want ?

Comment: Are you talking about A, B, C, D, E headers ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want them to be display reversed. As an example, let say that instead of A was StackOverFlow. I want to display this word from bottom to top, not from left to right like it is in normal case. So the text should be vertical not horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin` and `transform`. Here is [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/)

Answer (score 1):

Easy with flex, just use

```
{flex-direction: column-reverse;}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe we need a little bit more of your code.
On the first view it i would recommend you to check if your are using the table tags correct.

[tables in html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

If you want more help you should provide something like a fiddle.

regards